# Linked List model in Google App Engine Java

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I am a beginner in Java and the Google App Engine (java).

I am trying to make a linked list type of model to link up entities together. 
For example, I would like Class Fruit to be able to hold or take in a list of fruits, like Apple, Oranges...etc.
I was thinking of using the entity key as pointers between Class Fruit, and class Apple or class Orange.
Is there a way to grab an entity's key, and place it into another entity?
Better yet, grab multiple entity keys and place it into one entity?

Comment: did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Objectify - https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/ they have a really nice wrapper on top of the datastore that handles doing this for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it, but what exactly is a wrapper? Is it like JDO? so if I use Objectify, I would not be able to do JDO, or I guess that would be redundant?

Comment: Yes and yes. It's an API that replaces JDO and is designed specifically for appengine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with [Mungo-Appengine](https://github.com/pagecrumb/mungo) which has a MongoDB-like syntax with zero-configuration:

```
  Mungo mungo = new Mungo(); 
  DB fruitsDB = mungo.getDB("fruitsDB");
  DBCollection fruits = fruitsDB.createCollection("fruits");

  DBObject apple = new BasicDBObject("name", "apple")
                       .put("color", "red");

  DBObject orange = new BasicDBObject("name", "orange")
                       .put("color", "orange")
                       .put("weight", 1); 

  DBObject myBasket = new BasicDBObject("name", "myBasket")
         .put("fruits", Lists.newArrayList(apple, orange)); // Google Guava

  fruits.insert(myBasket); // Done!

  DBObject theBasket = fruits.findOne("{'name' : 'myBasket'}"); // Get it
  List<DBObject> theFruits = theBasket.get("fruits");
```

Hope this helps.